# How can I compute how many and which quartic invariants of a given group representation are linearly independent?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, mathematical-physics, symmetry

Given a representation $R$ of a group $G$ and the corresponding tensor product

$$ R \otimes R = R_1 \oplus R_2 \oplus R_3 \oplus \ldots $$

how can I compute how many quartic terms $ \mathrm{O} (R^4) \sim 1$ are linearly independent?

For example, given the adjoint $24$ of $SU(5)$, we have

$$ 24\otimes 24 = 1_s \oplus 24_s \oplus 24_a \oplus 75_s \oplus 126_a \oplus \overline{126_a} \oplus 200_s ,$$

where each representation is denoted by its dimension and the subscripts $s$ and $a$ denote symmetric and antisymmetric respectively. Naively, I would say we have 7 quartic invariants:

$$ (24\otimes 24)_{1_s} (24\otimes 24)_{1_s}  +  (24\otimes 24)_{24_s} (24\otimes 24)_{24_s} +  (24\otimes 24)_{24_a} (24\otimes 24)_{24_a} + (24\otimes 24)_{75_s} (24\otimes 24)_{75_s} + (24\otimes 24)_{126_a} (24\otimes 24)_{126_a} + (24\otimes 24)_{\overline{126_a}} (24\otimes 24)_{\overline{126_a}}  +(24\otimes 24)_{200_s} (24\otimes 24)_{200_s}  ,$$

because

$$ 1_s \otimes 1_s = 1 \quad  24_s \otimes 24_s =1 \quad  75_s \otimes 75_s =1 \quad etc. $$

**Nevertheless, apparently only two of them are linearly independent. How can I compute how many and which of these 7 terms are linearly independent?**

EDIT: For some reason a criterion seems to be how many representations appear in the symmetric part of the tensor product $R \otimes R$, as stated  [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=dRnaBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA28&lpg=PA28&dq=Higgs%20potential%20antisymmetric%20product%20vanishes&source=bl&ots=5RNVAs_FFD&sig=ysz_Sx2hIcyi9DTBb9KuH-r3y_8&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAGoVChMI6JDG-86ryAIVQWoaCh07owa-#v=onepage&q=Higgs%20potential%20antisymmetric%20product%20vanishes&f=false), but I have no idea why.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by a quartic invariant here (what do you mean by $O(R^4)$?).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft a quartic invariant is an order four term in the adjoint $24$-dimensional representation, which is invariant under the group, i.e. a singlet. For example, we can multiply the $24$ with itself, in such a way that the product transforms as the 75 dimensional representation $(24 \otimes 24)_{75}$. Then we can multiply this with itself in such a way that it is a singlet $((24 \otimes 24)_{75}(24 \otimes 24)_{75} )_1 $ i.e. transforms as the 1-dimensional representation.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Another possibility would be multiplying two $24$ representations in such a way that they transform as the $1$-dimensional representation (ordinary matrix multiplication and then taking the trace) and then multiplying this quadratic term with itself $((24 \otimes 24)_{1}(24 \otimes 24)_{1} )_1 $. As noted in the OP there are seven possibilities to multiply four $24$ representations and get something invariant, but these aren't all linearly independent apparently.

Comment: What are terms of a representation, and what does it mean for them to have order $4$?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft With terms of a representation I mean, for example, if we write a representation like the adjoint $24$-dimensional representation as a matrix $\phi$ something like $\phi \cdot \phi$, where the dot denotes ordinary matrix multiplication. This is an order two term. Another order two term is $Tr(\phi \cdot \phi)$, which is in addition an invariant, because it transforms as the $1$-dimensional representation. Order four terms are then $Tr(\phi \cdot \phi) Tr(\phi \cdot \phi) $ or $\phi \cdot \phi \cdot \phi \cdot \phi$ etc.

Comment: By writing a representation as a matrix, do you mean picking a matrix for each element of the group? I am also not sure what you mean by something transforming like a certain representation.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes, each element of the group gets represented by a matrix. In my understanding a representation is a map (homomorphism) from the group to the linear operators over a vector space, which in most applications means matrices. With a given representation $R$, we can get new representations through the Kronecker product $ R\otimes R$, i.e. product representations. In general the product representation is reducible and can be decomposed into irreducible parts, for example the antisymmetric and the symmetric part of the product.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with the tensor product of representations, but it seems like you want to multiply the individual matrices instead, which does not lead to a representation in general.